# Use Ajax to filter Rails database on jQuery click event?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have tables Projects which have and belong to many Categories. On the main page I display all projects. There is an on-click event for each Category, and I want the database to filter Projects by that category. Can someone help me with a framework to accomplish this? I'm a complete beginner to AJAX, let alone with jquery/rails.

Bonus points if that solution allows the user to click more than one and show BOTH categories of posts in the feed.

Thanks in advance!

Models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :filename, :location, :uploaded_file, :project_id, :category_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  def to_hash
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :filename => self.filename,
      :location => self.location,
    }
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :id, :category_id, :project_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
    def to_hash
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :name => self.name
    }
  end
end


class Category_Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :category_id
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :category
  def to_hash
    {
      :project_id => self.project_id
      :category_id => self.category_id
    }
  end
end
```

The AJAX call in my jQuery onclick function. "cat" is the name of one of the established category names.

```
...
    params = 'category_name=' + cat;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/projects_controller/filter_list",
            data: params
})
```

My view just does a @projects.each do |project| function.

Relevant function in projects_controller:

```
def filter_list
     @projects = Project.includes(:categories).where("categories.name = ?", params[:category_name])
    respond_to do |format|
      change_color.js /// Is this right?? This is same .js file my onclick event is in.
     end  
end
```

But, when I test it out and click the tab for Category "Food," nothing happens and I get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: It would help if you could show what you have so far (especially your view and controller).

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with your routes. Can you post your routes.rb file as well?

Comment: Your rails console should also be able to provide more information.

Comment: I fixed the routes file. Updated my problem.

Comment: It should be `:conditions => ["categories.name = ?"]`. Or better yet (assuming you're using rails 3), you can change the whole line to `@projects = Project.includes(:categories).where("categories.name = ?", params[:category_name])`

Comment: Thank you! Now I get a 500 internal server error :(

Comment: There you go. Came up with a proper answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. The the more railsy way is to have your ajax call return a js script that it then executes.

First, alter your ajax call to the following

```
params = 'category_name=' + cat;
$.ajax({
    url: "/projects_controller/filter_list",
    data: params,
    dataType: 'script'
});
```

This tells jQuery to expect a javascript file back from the server and to execute it once retrieved. You could replace this with

```
$.getScript('/projects_controller/filter_list?category_name=' + cat);
```

Alter your controllers respond_to block like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Now you'll need a `filter_list.js.erb` file in your views directory (wherever it goes -- `views/projects/filter_list.js.erb`?).

Assuming your projects/index looks like this:

```
<div class="projects">
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= render project %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

You'll want to put something like the following in your new js.erb file:

```
$('.projects').empty();
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  $('.projects').append("<%= escape_javascript render(project) %>");
<% end %>
```

This will replace the projects div on the current page with the new (filtered) project templates from your controller.

Comment: Actually..I still get a 500 internal server error. any ideas? :(

Comment: 500 server error says nothing. Check your rails console log. It will give you the relevant info.